# Algorithm to count instances of a value from a file

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am reading through a file of financial data with beneficiaries. I need to count the number of beneficiaries and then calculate their allocated percentage. If there is 1 beneficiary, the allocation is 100%, if there are 2, if there are 3, 33.33%, etc. The file is sorted by investment then beneficiary, so if there is more than one beneficiary per investment they will be in order in the file. Here's an example:

input file data

[image: beneficiary input file]

the output that I want

[image]

Here is my code, but it's wrong because this way I am assigning 100% to the first beneficiary, 50% to the second beneficiary, 33.333% to the third, etc. How can I change it to do the count, then create the beneficiaries with the right count? (There is an outer loop which is a table of investments.)

```
iBeneficiaryCount = 0.
dTempPercentage = 100.
FOR EACH ttJointData WHERE ttJointData.inv-num EQ ttInvestment.inv-num:
    IF ttJointData.Joint_Type EQ "Joint" THEN DO:
        cTemp = "JT".
        RUN CreateOwner (....).
   END.
   ELSE IF ttJointData.Joint_Type EQ "Beneficiary" THEN DO:
        iBeneficiaryCount = iBeneficiaryCount + 1.
        dTempPercentage = 100 / iBeneficiaryCount.
        RUN AddBeneficiary(ttJointData.investment-num,ttInvestment.benficiary-id,dTempPercentage).
    END.
END.
```

What are the best ways to capture that beneficiary percentage? I am thinking that I need to read through the data and put that value into the ttJointData table. Or is there a way to do it on the loop? Regardless, I need a neat algorithm to count up the instances from an input file and create and assign a percentage value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query to calculate the number of beneficiaries before you loop through them.

Something like

```
DEFINE VARIABLE dTempPercentage  AS DECIMAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iBeneficiaryCount AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE QUERY qryJD FOR ttJointData.

dTempPercentage = 100.
FOR EACH ttInvestment:
    // calculate how many beneficiaries; must use PRESELECT here
    OPEN QUERY qryJD PRESELECT EACH ttJointData WHERE ttJointData.inv-num EQ ttInvestment.inv-num.
    iBeneficiaryCount = QUERY qryJD:NUM-RESULTS.
    dTempPercentage = 100 / iBeneficiaryCount.

    GET FIRST qryJD .
    DO WHILE AVAILABLE ttJointData :
       IF ttJointData.Joint_Type EQ "Joint" THEN DO:
            cTemp = "JT".
            RUN CreateOwner (....).
       END.
       ELSE IF ttJointData.Joint_Type EQ "Beneficiary" THEN DO:
            RUN AddBeneficiary(ttJointData.investment-num,ttInvestment.benficiary-id,dTempPercentage).
        END.    

        GET NEXT qryJD .
    END.

    CLOSE QUERY qryJD.
END.
```

Comment: This solution worked beautifully and sped things up. I had come up with creating a second version of JointData with a BUFFER and looping through that to get the count., but this is more concise for sure.  Can you explain the WITH DOWN statement? I haven't seen that and can't find online documentation.

Comment: The `WITH DOWN` stuff was from my test code - it is used when using the `DISPLAY` statement in a frame. It's not necessary at all for the query and/or calculation. Check out the doc at https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/DEFINE-FRAME-statement.html?labelkey=product_openedge_125 and https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/Frame-phrase.html#Frame-phrase